# Why does Elastic Cloud provides a specialized port (9243) instead of only using the default one (443)?

Tags: http, elasticsearch, https, elastic-stack, elastic-cloud

I've just set up an Elastic Cloud deployment and was wondering why my endpoint has a specific port (9243) while the default HTTPS one, 443, also works?

- Will this behaviour change in the future?
- Will one of the ports be phased out?
- Which one should I use to start with?

On the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-enterprise/current/ece-connect.html), I can only find this:

> Port 9200 is used for HTTP connections, ports 9243 and 443 are used for HTTPS. Using HTTPS is generally recommended, as it is more secure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I received this answer from the Elastic Cloud helpdesk:

> Thank you for reaching out. You are correct that we allow both port
>   9243 and 443 for HTTPS in Elastic Cloud. There is no functional
>   difference whether you use one port or the other for HTTPS, and we
>   have no plans to phase one of the ports out. It is completely up to
>   you which port you decide to start with.

Comment: I was trying to establish connection using my server side PHP code to elastic server with 9243 port but it was giving `connection refused` error. I tried with 443 and it works without errors! Just adding in case someone else faces similar error due to port.

Answer (score 2):

I don’t believe the behaviour will change in the future. However, I would recommend sending an email to support@elastic.co to understand why 2 ports for HTTPS access.